# rails facebooker vs facebook js sdk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebooker

I am exploring facebook integration with my rails app and wondering what is the best practice for rails applications.

1 - Is js sdk the better route or the facebooker gem? I would like to allow users to login via facebook, post content/links to their walls, see friend activity in the application, invite fb friends, from the rails app etc.

2 - Can either of these methods be tested locally or do I need a hosted internet app?

3 - I already do fb authentication for login using janrain/rpx-now via authlogic-rpx plugin. Will this have any conflict with the facebooker gem or the fb js sdk. And..in order to use the fb pluging/js sdk/facebooker etc, is it required to do the authentication via those methods or can I authenticate via rpx/janrain but access feeds/friend activity etc from the facebooker gem/js sdk etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1) I often use both. I find most of the work to be easier using the server side SDK, but we do occasionally use the js one as well. I would check out Facebooker2, it's much more simple than the original Facebooker

2) Both can be used locally, but you do need internet connectivity to talk to Facebook.

3) If you get a valid access token, you can use Facebooker with the RPX stuff. You would need to change the way you do the client setup.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Can you please add more detail to #3 if possible?

Comment: Sure, if RPX gives you access to an access_token, you can do Mogli::Client.new(access_token) and then use it just like any other Mogli client